# Mule Datamapper JSON to XML Transformation

Tags: mule, datamapper

JSON Input Payload information, Where i have issue with.

```
{
"name": "xyz",
"city": "california",
"serialNumber": [ 
   "T2323" , 
   "T2332" 
]
}
```

Expected transformed Output Payload :

```
<COMPANY_ITEM_INFO>
     <COMPANY_NAME>xyz</COMPANY_NAME>
     <COMPANY_CITY>california</COMPANY_NAME>
     <Inv_Update SEGMENT="1"> 
         <SERIALNO>T2323</SERIALNO>  
     </Inv_Update SEGMENT="1">  
     <Inv_Update SEGMENT="1"> 
         <SERIALNO>T2332</SERIALNO>
     </Inv_Update SEGMENT="1">
</COMPANY_ITEM_INFO>
```

Actual Output received from Datamapper only 1 element as output.

```
<COMPANY_ITEM_INFO>
    <COMPANY_NAME>xyz</COMPANY_NAME>
    <COMPANY_CITY>california</COMPANY_NAME>
    <Inv_Update SEGMENT="1"> 
        <SERIALNO>T2323</SERIALNO> 
    </Inv_Update SEGMENT="1"> 
</COMPANY_ITEM_INFO>
```

Datamapper Code:

Foreach 'Object' - > 'COMPANY_ITEM_INFO'

```
//MEL
//START -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.__id = input.__id;
//END -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.COMPANY_NAME= input.name;
output.COMPANY_CITY= input.city;
```

ForEach 'serialNumber' -> 'Inv_Update'

```
//MEL
//START -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.__id = input.__id;
output.__parent_id = input.__id;
//END -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.SERIALNO = input.array;
```

Comment: Please share the xsd  used in both ends.

Comment: Maybe screen shot of the datamapper would be useful too

Comment: I doubt, problem would be in the dataType of SERIALNO or array( Complex or simpleType , Problem might be in XSD). Thought of referring it once.

Comment: @star <xs:element type="Inv_UpdateType" name="Inv_Update" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/> AND <xs:complexType name="Inv_UpdateType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SERIALNO"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="SEGMENT" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're looking for a DataMapper solution but in case you're open to alternative, below is a Groovy implementation (*since DataMapper is going away, now that [Weave is coming](https://www.mulesoft.com/integration-solutions/dataweave-integration), you should be open for options right?*).

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer
    returnClass="java.lang.Object" />

<scripting:transformer>
  <scripting:script engine="groovy"><![CDATA[
    def writer = new StringWriter() 
    def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)

    xml.COMPANY_ITEM_INFO { 
      COMPANY_NAME(payload.name) 
      COMPANY_CITY(payload.city) 

      payload.serialNumber.each { sn ->
        Inv_Update(SEGMENT: '1') {
          SERIALNO(sn)
        }
      }
    }

    result = writer.toString()
  ]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>
```

Comment: Yes you right. It can be done using Groovy. Do you know is this a limitation of Data Mapper at this moment ? By any chance if you know how this can be done using Data Mapper.

Comment: I reckon this can be done with DM, yes, I don't know how and, since it's going away anyway, no real perks in learning it further :D

Comment: Got it... All right.. And how about checking NULL Values in Groovy if INPUT JSON Payload doesn't have 'name' element populated as part of INPUT payload.. What do i need to change in your proposed code to take care those situations ?

Comment: What behaviour do you want in case of null?

Comment: This is my REQUEST Payload looks like -> {
"city": "california",
"serialNumber": [ 
   "T2323" , 
   "T2332" 
]
} I didn't provided name field as part of input payload. How should i take of this situation in your code ?

Comment: My Output Payload supposed to look like this...... <COMPANY_ITEM_INFO>
     <COMPANY_CITY>california</COMPANY_NAME>
     <Inv_Update SEGMENT="1"> 
         <SERIALNO>T2323</SERIALNO>  
     </Inv_Update SEGMENT="1">  
     <Inv_Update SEGMENT="1"> 
         <SERIALNO>T2332</SERIALNO>
     </Inv_Update SEGMENT="1">
</COMPANY_ITEM_INFO>

Comment: Try with: `if (payload.name) COMPANY_NAME(payload.name)`

Comment: Thanks David that worked for me... You are Mule Guru who knows much more then any Mule internal Developer :)